# DBAL QueryBuilder : what is the safier way to avoid SQL injection?

Tags: php, doctrine, sql-injection, query-builder, dbal

According to the DBAL Documentation, only the method setFirstResult and setMaxResults are designed to be safe from SQL injections. But in QueryBuilder section they mention that to safely work with the QueryBuilder we have to pass user inputs with the setParameter method.
So i see 2 ways to doing that, but i don't know if they have real difference or not :
Way 1 :

```
$qb->select('USR_id', 'USR_email')
->from('T_user_USR')
->where('USR_email = ? ')
->setParameter(0, $email);
$stmtQb = $qb->execute();
$results = $stmtQb->fetchAll();
```

Way 2 :

```
$qb->select('USR_id', 'USR_email')
->from('T_user_USR')
->where('USR_email = ? ');
$stmtQb = $dbal->prepare($qb->getSQL());
$stmtQb->bindValue(1, $email);
$stmtQb->execute();
$results = $stmtQb->fetchAll();
```

What's the best way to do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two examples eventually do the same thing. That is, when you use `setParameter()` the parameter value is bound to the statement using `bindValue()`.

See https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php#L1326-L1356 for the internal function that does this in DBAL.

The only reason to use the second form is if you want to use `bindParam()` instead of `bindValue()`. You would do this if you wanted to bind the parameter to a PHP variable by reference, for example so you could prepare a query once before starting a loop, and then execute it many times in the loop.

Both methods give the same amount of protection with respect to SQL injection.

Comment: Thank for your answer Bill,

It's a bit hard for me to understand the DBAL's source code, but what i see is sufficient for understanding my problem.

I feel safe now :D

Comment: It takes lots of practice to develop a skill to read other source code. But it's a worthwhile thing to practice!